# Django HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and Amazon ELB

Tags: django

We have two Amazon EC2 instances, with a load balancer and a Django App.  Amazon says the ELB is configured by default to send `X-Forwarded-For` headers to the Django App.

I've printed `request.META` and I see no `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and when I do `request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')`, I get None.

Is there a django configuration (we're using 1.3 by the way), that I have to configure or set so that Django will read the Forwarded-For header?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: what mode do you use on ELB: http or tcp?

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko I'm not sure.  How would I find that out?  The sys admin setup the ELB, and I have no access to it.

Comment: Sam, I don't know either, but I heard that it can run on TCP level and there will be no header obviously. But I'm guessing it's not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more investigation, we discovered that ELB was forwarding to port 443 on TCP and Apache was handling the SSL cert.  In order to get ELB to forward X-Forwarded-For headers, it should be forwarding on HTTP, which also requires that the SSL Cert be installed on the ELB rather than on Apache.  Hope this helps others